# AP Statistics practice test question: Why is a two-proportion z-test invalid?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The question is as follows:

A pollster is interested in comparing the proportions of women and men in a particular town who are in favor of a ban on fireworks within town borders. The pollster plans to test the hypothesis that the proportion of women in favor of the ban is diﬀerent from the proportion of men in favor of the ban. There are 4,673 women and 4,502 men who live in the town. From a simple random sample of 40 women in the town, the pollster finds that 38 favor the ban. From an independent simple random sample of 50 men in the town, the pollster finds that 27 favor the ban. Which of the following statements is true about this situation?

(A) Because the samples are from normal populations, a two-proportion z-test would be valid.

(B) Because the size of each sample is greater than 30, a two-proportion z-test would be valid.

(C) Because the number who favored the ban is greater than 10 in both groups, a two-proportion z-test would be valid

(D) Because of the relative sizes of the populations and samples, a two-proportion z-test would be valid.

(E) A two-proportion z-test would not be valid for these data.

I know the answer is E, but why? I'm assuming the questions thinks a X^2 test of homogeneity should be used instead but can I determine that? What makes a two-proportion z-test invalid? p-bar * n1, q-bar * n1, p-bar * n2, q-bar * n2 are all greater than 5 so the conditions for a two-proportion test seem to be met. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You are testing between two proportions here. Look at your number of successes for females versus the total number of samples collected for females. Now, look at the requirements for using a z-test for two proportions.

Comment: Thanks! I looked it up online and one of the conditions described is that each sample includes at least 10 successes and 10 failures. I read through our text book and that's never mentioned. It says the conditions for this test are that p-bar * n1, q-bar * n1, p-bar * n2, q-bar * n2 all be greater than 5, which this question meets. Is the textbook just wrong or are there different acceptable conditions?